# how to make track progress bar using checkboxe value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to make track your progress section using checkbox values. So, how it works is simple. see there are two pages page one and page two. On page one there are some checkboxes and on page two there is a one progress bar. when user click on checkbox from page one it should increase value of progress bar from another page. But i dont know how to do this with two page. I have tried with one page only. Here is the code:

```js
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.progressbar_chkbox').on('click', function() {
   var currValue = 0;

  jQuery(".progressbar_chkbox:checked").each(function() {
 currValue += parseInt($(this).val());
   });

currValue = Math.min(currValue, 100);

 jQuery('#progress-bar').css('width', currValue + '%').attr('aria-valuenow',      
    currValue);   
     });
      });
```

```html
     <script  
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <!-- Begin checkboxes -->
   <div class="panelBody" id="panelBody1">

    <input id="input1" class="progressbar_chkbox videoChecks" 
     type="checkbox" name="completed1" value="20">
    <input id="input2" class="progressbar_chkbox videoChecks" 
     type="checkbox" name="completed2" value="20">
     <input id="input3" class="progressbar_chkbox videoChecks" 
    type="checkbox" name="completed3" value="20">
   <input id="input4" class="progressbar_chkbox videoChecks" type="checkbox" 
  name="completed4" value="20">
    <input id="input5" class="progressbar_chkbox videoChecks"  
   type="checkbox" name="completed5" value="20">
  
    </div>

      
        <div class="progress">
      <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"  
       role="progressbar" 
      aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: use localStorage

Comment: No. I dont think that will work. I think i try session. But i dont understand how send checkbox value from page to another

Comment: A "session" is usually used for server-side storage, you can implement that with php for example and keep the same javascript code. localStorage on the other hand is a client-side storage, I don't see why you say it won't work - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

here an exemple with localStorage. https://jsfiddle.net/3kg17kg8/2/

```js
$(function() {

  $('.progressbar_chkbox').click(function() {
  
   // Page 1
   var progress = $(this).data('progress');
    
 sessionStorage.setItem("progress", progress)
    
     
        // Page 2
    var progress = sessionStorage.getItem("progress");
    
        $('#avancement').val(progress);
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Page 1 -->
    <input class="progressbar_chkbox" type="checkbox" data-progress="20">
    <input class="progressbar_chkbox" type="checkbox" data-progress="40">
    <input class="progressbar_chkbox" type="checkbox" data-progress="60">
    <input class="progressbar_chkbox" type="checkbox" data-progress="80">
      
     <!-- Page 2 -->
    <p><progress id="avancement" value="0" max="100"></progress></p>
```

Comment: Yes try the fiddle (edited); Code Snippet can't use localStorage

Comment: Ok thanx. Can you tell me how this local storage works in short?

Comment: Hi, If you can help me please help. I am stuck. Your answer didn't helped me.